# How can I combine different fields with similar values into one column of a matrix? SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

How can I combine different fields with similar values into one column of a matrix?

For example, I have 4 fields. Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4. Each of these fields contain numbers 1-7.

I want to get the combined sum for all of the fields for number1, number2, number3, number4, number5, number6, and number7.

Some fields contain might be missing a few numbers.

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: It would be helpful when asking your question to provide some visual aid - either screenshots or mockups - of what you have now and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You can sum several fields like this: Fields!Field1.Value + Fields!Field2.Value. However if your fields contain a string with numbers separated by a `-` you need to process those strings to extract the numbers. What is your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert a blank column outside group right. Insert the following as an expression :

```
=Fields!Field1.Value+Fields!Field2.Value+Fields!Field3.Value+Fields!Field4.Value
```

This will sum the values , blank or null values will be ignored.

Comment: Whilst this will give you the result you are after, for future maintainability you would want to, if possible, add an additional field to your dataset that does the `sum` of the columns before returning the data to your report and then referencing that column in your Matrix.  This will perform faster and remove the need to update the column in the table if you add in new columns to the `sum` calculation.